# Breakpoint in console App visual studio

Tags: c#, debugging, console-application

I work on a project, where a process starts a console app on another thread and then it continues to its previous flow. I have attached the original process to the debugger, but I can't do that with the console app process, as that process doesn't get listed in the 'Attach to process' list. How can I debug the console app?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why it's not showing in the processes (have you made sure that All processes are showing?).

Anyway, try this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

and in your code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

You should then get a dialog when the code hits that line, allowing you to attach Visual Studio to the process.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check *Show processes from all users* and *Show processes in all sessions*

[image]

Comment: It doesn't get showed in the list, because it gets created at run time

Comment: Is there any idea of what my new console app process name would be?

Comment: @Krishnan, Once your console app launches, it should show up on this list with the name you see in TaskManager.  It does not matter if the secondary process is launched at run time.  Once the process starts, it should be visible within this window.